# What should be the base URL for the images in magento?

Tags: rest, http, magento, magento2

After accessing the Rest API (http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products/SKU) to get the product details, the response is something like this:

```
    {
      "attribute_code": "image",
      "value": "/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "small_image",
      "value": "/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
      "value": "/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg"
    }
```

What should be the base url for the jpg in the attribute_code keys ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for modifying the API request.

Just add a prefix: http://magento.com/pub/media/catalog/product/

So the new URL according to my response will be:

Prefix: http://magento.com/pub/media/catalog/product/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @return string */
function getMediaBaseUrl() {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $om */
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager */
    $storeManager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    /** @var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface|\Magento\Store\Model\Store $currentStore */
    $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
    return $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
}
```